# How do I make use of the eSATA port on my laptop with normal SATA drives?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata, esata

On my laptop I have an eSATA port. And I also have a SATA → eSATA cable.

I know that simply using that cable would never work as the SATA disks require an additional power cable. The question is: How are those eSATA ports supposed to work?

Where can I get the power cable? Or do actually I need special eSATA drives?

I tried to find eSATA disks and wasn't able to find them.

Comment: +1: Useful question for users that have the same doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to get a hard drive dock that is compatible with eSATA. [This one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-eSATA-SATA-External-Drive/sim/B0026B8VQQ/2) is an example of one that connects with both eSATA and USB but just google for eSATA dock and you'll get plenty of options.

If you want a prebuilt solution rather than using a drive you already have I found some by just googling esata drive [here's](http://www.amazon.co.uk/LaCie-Rugged-1TB-Hard-Disk/dp/B00270NXOQ/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1314105760&sr=8-2) one example.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a e-sata case. I search for some options and find [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Rocketfish-2-5-E-SATA-EXTERNAL-USB-HARD-DRIVE-CASE-KIT-/320739334605?pt=PCC_Drives_Storage_Internal&hash=item4aad8dd9cd) and [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Black-USB-eSATA-SATA-HDD-External-Enclosure-CASE-/280488162637?pt=PCC_Drives_Storage_Internal&hash=item414e65b54d). It will depend on the form factor of your sata disk drive(3,5 or 2,5')

Comment: if I could accept two answers, I would choose yours as well. THANK YOU!